# Gradient I created doesn't match up to values on axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to show a color gradient as the background of matplotlib chart.
I found [some code on the matplotlib site](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/gradient_bar.html) that is close to what I want.

But when using this example and creating my own colormap, the values I specify don't match up to the values on the axis.

For example, using the sample code above and...
Specifing my colors and values in a dict:

**Notice the 0.8 for the interval value, I expect the 0-0.8 to be black, and 0.8 to 1.0 to be a gradient of red to black.**

```
cdict1 = {
    'red': 
        [
            (0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            (0.8, 0.0, 0.0),
            (0.8, 1.0, 1.0),
            (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        ],
    'blue': [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)],
    'green': [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)]
 }
```

Converting the dict to a colormap:

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
testcm1 = LinearSegmentedColormap('testcm1 ', cdict1)
```

And changing the call of `gradient_image` to use my colormap:

```
gradient_image(ax, direction=0, extent=(0, 1, 0, 1), transform=ax.transAxes,
               cmap=testcm1 , cmap_range=(0, 1))
```

Yet my output shows the red-black gradient starting at about 0.72.
[image: output]

Naturally I expect the gradient to be exactly matched up to the 0.8 value on the y axis, and I have no idea what's happening here.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

import numpy as np

np.random.seed(19680801)

def gradient_image(ax, extent, direction=0.3, cmap_range=(0, 1), **kwargs):
    """
    Draw a gradient image based on a colormap.

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax : Axes
        The axes to draw on.
    extent
        The extent of the image as (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax).
        By default, this is in Axes coordinates but may be
        changed using the *transform* kwarg.
    direction : float
        The direction of the gradient. This is a number in
        range 0 (=vertical) to 1 (=horizontal).
    cmap_range : float, float
        The fraction (cmin, cmax) of the colormap that should be
        used for the gradient, where the complete colormap is (0, 1).
    **kwargs
        Other parameters are passed on to `.Axes.imshow()`.
        In particular useful is *cmap*.
    """
    phi = direction * np.pi / 2
    v = np.array([np.cos(phi), np.sin(phi)])
    X = np.array([[v @ [1, 0], v @ [1, 1]],
                  [v @ [0, 0], v @ [0, 1]]])
    a, b = cmap_range
    X = a + (b - a) / X.max() * X
    im = ax.imshow(X, extent=extent, interpolation='bicubic',
                   vmin=0, vmax=1, **kwargs)
    return im


xmin, xmax = xlim = 0, 10
ymin, ymax = ylim = 0, 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, autoscale_on=False)

cdict1 = {
    'red': 
        [
            (0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            (0.8, 0.0, 0.0),
            (0.8, 1.0, 1.0),
            (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        ],
    'blue': [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)],
    'green': [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)]
 }

testcm1 = LinearSegmentedColormap('testcm1', cdict1)

# background image
gradient_image(ax, direction=0, extent=(0, 1, 0, 1), transform=ax.transAxes,
               cmap=testcm1, cmap_range=(0, 1))

ax.set_aspect('auto')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd say there are only three anchor points, so the color dictionary should rather look like

```
'red': 
        [
            (0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            (0.8, 0.0, 1.0),
            (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        ],
```

But that's not really the problem here.

The real problem is that your image consists of the 4 corner points. bicubic interpolation will make the gradient; but of course you do not have enough resolution to show the exact gradient specified. In particular, 0.8 is not part of your image data.

One would hence need to define an image that has enough resolution to show the discontinuity. (In the following I also made the colormap creation a bit more intuitive.)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

colors = [(0, "black"),(0.8,"black"),(0.8,"red"),(1.0,"black")]
testcm2 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('testcm2', colors)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

X = np.repeat(np.linspace(0,1,301),2).reshape(301,2)
im = ax.imshow(X, extent=(0,1,0,1), cmap=testcm2, vmin=0, vmax=1, 
               interpolation="bicubic", origin="lower")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, incredible. Even simpler than the example on the actual matplotlib page. Is the 301 in your answer just a high number that bumps up the resolution?
I'll see how far I get adapting this for my real use case.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes, 301 is pretty arbitrary, just any number (n+1) where n is divisible by 5 would ensure that 0.8 is precisely part of the data, but if the number is high, you wouldn't see the difference anyways. Maybe note that the matplotlib example is "so complicated" because it allows for rotated gradients.